# error when i used unsafe keyword in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net

i used unsafe inside class but its not working. It gives error :

> Unsafe code may only appear if
>   compiling with /unsafe.

May i know how to use unsafe keyword in asp.net(visual studio 2008) page.

Asp.net c#

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `/unsafe` to the conditional compilation symbols under the `Build` tab in the project properties.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio (2005 - 2010), on the Project Properties page, in the Build tab, there's a checkbox that says "Allow unsafe code". You need to check this, and then re-build your project.

[image: screenshot from Visual Studio 2010]

Comment: under build tag there is no checkbox for  "Allow unsafe code".

Comment: I guess it depends on the version of Visual Studio. There's definitely one in VS 2010!

Comment: i am using VS 2008 so whats the solution?

Comment: I just looked at VS2008 and I could see the check box there. Are you sure you don't see that. Goto Properties, Select Build Tab, under General, you will see two check boxes, one is Allow Unsafe code and other is Optimize Code

Comment: @user707294 - see this MSDN page - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct597kb0(v=VS.90).aspx - the checkbox should be there on VS 2008 (and also VS 2005)

Answer (score 0):

If you use "unsafe" keyword within your project you need to include [/unsafe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct597kb0%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) upon compilation. This tells the JIT compiler to compile the unsafe code and allow it to run.